# Entity Framework - The foreign key component ... is not a declared property on type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I get this error:

The foreign key component 'SubdivisionHOAId' is not a declared property on type 'SubdivisionHOA'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

Here is my model.  I don't understand what I need to do, as my understanding is that if I've specified [ForeignKey("SubdivisionsHOA")], it refers to my navigation property in the same class, so shouldn't it try to link on the 'Id' of SubdivisionHOA?  I've been grappling with this for hours:

```
public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContentArticleHOA")]
    public long ContentArticleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubdivisionsHOA")]
    public short SubdivisionHOAId { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentArticleHOA ContentArticleHOA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubdivisionHOA
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("TopTierDivisionHOA")]
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual TopTierDivisionHOA TopTierDivisionHOA { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add a property of the related entity type, in your case SubdivisionHOA, and add foreign key attribute to that property

```
public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{

    public short SubdivisionHOAId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubdivisionsHOAId")]    
    public virtual SubdivisionHOA SubdivisionHOA {get;set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By now you have solved this but for anyone with the same problem here is the solution.

The ForeignKey attribute attribute should be on your other class `SubdivisionHOA`

Your `ContentArticleHOAsubdivision` class has a list of `SubdivisionHOA` and you don't need to add a Foreign Key to the List of values. You add the ForeignKey attribute to the class having the one (of a one-many relationship) relationship.Ideally your classes should be like this

```
    public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContentArticleHOA")]
    public long ContentArticleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentArticleHOA ContentArticleHOA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubdivisionHOA
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("TopTierDivisionHOA")]
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("ContentArticleHOAsubdivision")]
    public short ContentArticleHOAsubdivision{ get; set; }

    public virtual TopTierDivisionHOA TopTierDivisionHOA { get; set; }
}
```